# sig in pthread_kill(pthread_t thread, int sig)

Tags: c++, pthreads

What does sig in int pthread_kill(pthread_t thread, int sig) refer to? Are there predefined sigs? :S

Answer (score 2):

In reply to your comment about interrupting sleep: Instead of attempting to force signals to work here, have you considered instead of `sleep` using `pthread_cond_timedwait` instead? It lets you effectively sleep and provides a thread-safe mechanism to abort the sleep early via a `pthread_cond_signal`.

Comment: I did consider it but I am trying to avoid using conditions, if that is possible.

Comment: @return: That seems some strange reasoning: avoiding condition variables, but then resorting to signals, especially since you don't seem to be comfortable with signal-handlers.  Any reasons why?

Answer (score 0):

sig is for signal number sending to the thread. Standard signals are described in . For example [linux standard signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

pthread_kill() will not kill a thread. The only difference with kill() is that the signal is handled by the designated thread and not handled while that thread has the signal masked (see pthread_sigmask()). A signal like SIGTERM will by default still terminate the entire process.